# Muktzeh Because its assur for me

Tags: passover, yom-kippur, muktzeh, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, gebrochts

The question is for food on Yom Kippur, or Gebrokts or Kitnyos on Pesach (for those that do not eat them), are they Muktzeh?

Comment: The kitniyos would [still be usable](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6847/1172).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [88:3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%A4%D7%97#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.92) says they are not.

Comment: It mentions these specific cases?!

Comment: @SimchasTorah No, I took the liberty of applying his rule regarding things that are אסור לאכילה ומותר להנאה to your cases.

Comment: OK thanks for the input I think Reb Akivah Eiger says the food is Muktzeh on Yom Kippur though

Comment: @R'WAF, but gebrokts is אסור בהנאה for those who forbid it (AFAIK; CYLOR). But פמ״ג א״א שלח:ג (cited also by the ביה״ל there) may be relevant. As always, CYLOR.

Comment: @msh210, Really? Ad k'dei kach? If some water falls on a gebrokts-keeper's matza, he can't even give it to his dog? If a gebrokts-keeper is at a meal at which both gebrokts and non-gebrokts are served, he can't pass the gebrokts to his Litvish co-diner?

Comment: Well, more precisely, I've never heard that it's _asur b'hanaa_. But certainly we don't own it on _Pesach_ (and hence don't give it to our dogs). YMMV (your _minhag_ may vary).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I don't think people make food muktza for Yom kippur since they need it for children.  (inedibles like raw chicken would be just like shabbos).

As far as food being asur, the [Mishna Berura 308:170](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=223) quotes "poskim" that an object's muktza status depending on the owner is only when the object is rejected because of its poor quality, but if someone made a neder and the object is now forbidden, he can still move it since it is permitted to others.  That should apply to Yom Kippur (Children), Gebrochts (us non-gebrochtsers) and kitnios (sefardim).