# Kitniyos Hanaah

Tags: passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

There's been a lot of buzz about Kitzniyos here recently. If I remember correctly, things with Kitniyos are only prohibited to be eaten (according to those with the Minhag), and are okay to benefit from.

Am I correct?

And if so, where's the boundary (i.e. גדר) between pleasure and eating. (e.g. smoking, injecting)

Comment: The Geder of eating should be the same in all applications (non-kosher food,etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *T'rumas Hadeshe"n* ([#113](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45311&st=&pgnum=97)) allows getting non-eating benefit from *kitniyos*.

Comment: He mentions those who actually tried to forbid it but he said that such a custom is incorrect.

Comment: Any idea where smoking or injecting fit in?

Comment: Injecting is definitely not eating. Smoking is a little more of a cloudy issue. ;-)

Comment: The truth is that smoking is most likely not derech achilah and therefore as far as kitniyos goes it would not be a problem.